# Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value after IAP is complete

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, option-type

In my app the user has the ability to purchase stars from the main game screen. Using Ray Wenderlich's IAP tutorial I'm able to set up and implement the consumable IAP without a hitch until I try to update the label which states the number of stars the user has.

I use an IAPHelper swift file which does the heavy lifting and utilise the following function to call my 'addStars' function within my gameScreen viewController once the purchase goes through:

```
private func complete(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
    print("complete...")

    deliverPurchaseNotificationFor(identifier: transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)

    gameScreen().addStars(number_of_stars: 50)

}
```

In gameScreen my addStars function is as follows:

```
func addStars(number_of_stars: Int)
{
    self.stars = self.stars + number_of_stars
    self.starsLabel.text = String(self.stars)
}
```

and here is where I get an Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value error.

I understand this is because my starsLabel is now nil but I don't understand how to make this work. I've tried various online tutorials/questions to no avail.

What do I need to do after completion of the purchase before I can update the starsLabel?

Comment: `gameScreen()` is creating a new, unused instance that isn't initialized from the storyboard. You probably want to access your existing game screen, not attempt to create a new one.

Comment: Comparable to http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake/ even though in this case it's not a view controller.

Answer (score 0):

rmaddy, you're absolutely right - it did create an unused instance and that was the issue. I managed to solve it by creating notifications between the IAPHelper and gameScreen classes, now it works as intended. Thanks for the help.